# Structures Program not working as intended (Bug)

Tags: c, file, structure

I have been working on reading data from a file, which contains student name and age in the format:

John

12

Jane

13

Julia

18

Here's the program I wrote:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    struct record{
        char name[50];
        int age;
    };
    int main(){
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("sample2.txt","r");
        struct record a[50];
        int counter=1;
        int i=0;
        while (!EOF){
        if (counter%2!=0){
            fgets(a[i].name,50,fp);
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter%2==0){
            a[i].age=getw(fp);
            counter++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

However, on printing a[0].name, I am not getting expected output. Can someone help?

Comment: `EOF` is a negative constant defined in `<stdio.h>`, usually −1. It is not zero, so it's always true and `!EOF` is always false – your program doesn't enter the loop. There's another issue when you read the age: `getw` reads a (raw / binary) machine word. Read a line with `fgets`, then convert it to an integer with `strtol` or `atoi`.

Comment: 'counter' is pretty pointless.
You should check what getw does. Assuming "12" is ascii in the file and not actually a word, followed by a newline. => so there's your problem. you could use instead fgets() + atoi().
Best practice would be to print things as you read them with a special log, so that it's clearer to you.

Comment: @MOehm I got your points but I couldn't figure out how to edit the while loop so that loop works as long as end of file is not reached.

Comment: @MOehm I couldn't get what you mean by raw/machine word

Comment: There are two basic modes of in-/output: Raw or binary data and text data. Your file is a text file. Use `fprintf`, `fgets`, `fscanf` and so on for text data. Use `fread`and `fwrite` for raw data. `getw` is an old function that reads four bytes and treats them as an `int`, juat as a program might treat four bytes in memory as `int`.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, EOF is a value defined in stdio.h and does not say anything about your file descriptor. I also would recommend you to use fscanf (As long you are sure that the names in the file are all of the correct length). fscanf takes a string similar to printf, specifying the elements you are expecting and returns the number of possible matches. Also it helps you with converting your data to the correct datatypes. So the code could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct record
{
  char name[50];
  int age;
};

int main ()
{
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen ("sample2.txt", "r");
  struct record a[50];
  int i = 0;
  while (fscanf(fp, "%s\n%d\n", (char *) a[i].name, &a[i].age) > 0) {
    i++;
  }
  printf("%s %d\n", a[1].name, a[1].age);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `> 0` ==> `== 2` , The scanf family doesn't return the "number of possible matches", it returns the number of *actual* arguments properly formatted and parsed. Also I'm not sure what you think the extraneous cast `(char *)` against `a[i].name` is accomplishing, but it isn't necessary. And add is a proper length limit on the string format specifier. I.e. `%49s`